# Why two documents with same dimension but different resolution has different view size in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, ppi

please look at these pictures. i couldn't figure out, why this happens?
[image]

Comment: ppi means pixel per inch. If your document is 1*1inch at 27ppi that means it is 27x27 pixels. If your document is 1*1 inch at 72 it means your document is 72x72px.

Comment: okay but why in same view size (100%) i see one bigger than another?

Comment: because one *IS* bigger than the other!

Comment: I’m not a native speaker, so please excuse if my explanation does sound clumsy, but I’ll do my best :) — Photoshop only displays the actual pixels of an image. That means that one pixel (at 100%) has exactly the same size as one pixel of your screen. So naturally the image with more pixels in it will be displayed larger. BUT: If you were to safe these files and load them for example in an InDesign-document, they will have the same dimensions (at different resolutions), because InDesign in contrast to Photoshop actually makes use of the ppi information in the file. I hope I could help.

Comment: @mnxd your explanation was a lot clearer than a lot of native speakers'!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, when your working on a screen, forget about physical dimensions and resolution (PPI). All that affects the size you see something on screen is its pixel dimensions. Your screen doesn't know what an inch is, all it knows is pixels.

In your examples:

- 1×1 inch image at 72PPI is 72×72 pixels.
- 1×1 inch image at 27PPI is 27×27 pixels.

Your screen shows those images at their *pixel* size, ignoring any physical dimensions or resolution settings.

If you were to print those images they would both print at 1 inch square. The only time the resolution really comes in to play is when you print.

If you were to import your images in to say InDesign, they would both show at 1x1 inch because InDesign is resolution aware. This is because InDesign is made for (or at least was traditionally) print design—where resolution really matters.

Comment: and on a paper?

Comment: On paper, both will print at 1 inch. I'll update my answer when I'm back at my computer.

Comment: thanks, okay screen just see pixels but why printer just didn't see dots instead inch or cm and so on?

Comment: Pretty much. Some programs are *resolution aware*, but that tends to just be stuff geared towards print design, which is when you should worrying about this stuff... If you're working for screen, forget about it. Just think about pixels.

Comment: @programmer1 Different technology base. making a image by controlling output directly is much harder so printers have abstracted away the rasterisation prococess. The pixels on a screen are much more straightforward. Also your operating system does not know how big your screen is.

Comment: My brain is now frozen completely!

Comment: @joojaa stop confusing people :p

Comment: Simply printer does not work like a monitor. it does not mix color per dot bit rather mixes ccolors in a cluster of dots this density is called a line. @programmer1 think of it thisway you can not affect the size of a monitor, the user may change settings and what you see is differently sized so sending physical size is mostly meaningless but on paper once its on the paper the size will generally stay that size forever.

Comment: "the size will generally stay that size forever" assuming no gravitational waves :). When one considers a 50 inch monitor and a 13 inch monitor, both at 1920px x 1080 px, it becomes a little clearer what joojaa is describing.

Comment: @Yorik yes but even a 1920*1080 monitor may in fact be configured as a 720x400 pixels a paper does not change on the whim of its user. Ok so it crumples but i can also trash a monitor.

Comment: I'm not sure how much you two are helping... :p

Answer (score 0):

Your screen's resolution (as are most screen resolutions) 72 ppi. If you change the resolution to be higher, it will appear larger on your screen to achieve the same visual "density" if you will. Likewise, when the resolution is lower, it will appear smaller.

Allow me a metaphor.

Imagine you cover 1 sq. inch with 72 cheerios and you are looking at it from 3 feet away. Now imagine you remove cheerios till you are left with 27 cheerios, but those cheerios have taken on milk and are much larger to fill the space. **In order for those cheerios to appear the same size as the 72 did before, you have to look at it from further away. Thus, the smaller square.**

Comment: Most screens are  not 72 ppi. 72 PPI is just the magick number that makes a postscript point equal to a pixel. User mnxd and the answe of CAI is correct.

Comment: Screens havn't actually been 72PPI in about 30 years. It was only a standard for Macs and it didn't last very long.. Also changing the resolution of an image makes no difference to how you see it on screen.

Comment: Talking exclusively about photoshop, which is the only one of the creative suite that uses pixels as its primary framework. And as the question noted, it actually appears smaller and provides less pixels to use within an artboard. So yes, there is a difference in Photoshop. And it's also why the standard resolution for exporting any assets to the web is 72ppi, and @2x simulates retina.

Comment: No. Not at all. Images at a different resolution and the same physical dimension will look different but that is because the pixel size is changing. They look different in Photoshop because they *are* different sizes. One is 72 pixels the other is 27 pixels.

Comment: Make a 100x100px image and save it at 72ppi... Make anther 100x100px image and save t at 300ppi... They look exactly the same on screen. No difference at all. The only thing that matters is pixels.

Comment: I agree with you, but we are saying two different things. I'm directly addressing the question where the document size isn't based off of pixels, but inches. Since you only design in inches with an intent to print, resolution matters, and it matters what the resolution of your document is at that point too.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. The screen resolution definitely isn't 72ppi though ;)